# destructuting is not happening with string from array

Tags: javascript, destructuring

i am trying to destructure an array and return an object. but the key is not working inside the object. but outside of the object destructuring happening smoothly.

```
let [key, value] = ["b", 2];
    
let object = { key: value };

console.log(object); // {key: 2}

console.log(key, value)// b, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation!

To use a variable as a key in objects...

Because when creating an object, the parser interprets the string in front of `:` as a key.
The string after the `:` for sure has to be a variable if it isn't wrapped with quotes to specify a string.
So for the key, it does not know you want to use the variable named like that string.
How to tell it is the brackets use.

```js
let [key, value] = ["b", 2];
    
let object = { [key]: value };  // Brackets around the key variable

console.log(object); // {"b": 2}  As expected...

console.log(key, value)// b, 2
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  can you just a little bit add why should i use Brackets around the key variable?

Comment: Sure... Done in my own words... Hoping it helps.